# Windows Cryptography Next Generation (CNG) is not supported on this platform PowerShell from AWS-Lambda

Tags: powershell, aws-lambda, powerbi

Below is the code that I have been trying to get working from a Linux based AWS Lambda that runs PowerShell and/or C#.  The code was adapted from [this blog](https://endjin.com/blog/2020/12/how-to-update-credentials-for-an-on-prem-power-bi-data-source-using-powershell) that discusses updating credentials programmatically via PowerShell.  Locally, I can run this series of code called from a python script using `subprocess.Popen` with no issues (from a Windows machine).  However, AWS is not the same.  Needless to say, I have hit a wall when it comes to trying to encrypt credentials in order to make a patch request to the Power BI API (source here:  [Power BI Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/gateways/updatedatasource)).  Since we are working in AWS and our deployments are done through Bamboo, the option to compile via C# and then deploy through the CLI is not available so any documentation about CLI isn't of value in this current process.

```
$credentialDetails = [Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.Models.CredentialDetails]::new(
        $basicCreds, 
            [Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.Models.PrivacyLevel]::Private, 
            [Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.Models.EncryptedConnection]::Encrypted, 
            $credentialsEncryptor)
```

Trying to run the above code returns:

```
    b'\nGAC    Version        Location\n---    -------        --------\nFalse  v4.0.30319     
opt/layer/modules/Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.2.3.22/l\xe2\x80\xa6\nFalse  v4.0.30319     
opt/layer/powershell/Newtonsoft.Json.dll\nFalse  v4.0.30319     
opt/layer/modules/Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.3.20.0/lib/nets\xe2\x80\xa6\nDidn\'t get past creating the 
credential details\n"Exception calling \\".ctor\\" with \\"4\\" argument(s): \\"Windows Cryptography Next 
Generation (CNG) is not supported on this platform.\\""\n'
```

You guys have really helped me out with a few issues, this would be clutch if you could provide any valuable insight on how to effectively encrypt credentials to Windows expectations via Linux.

Comment: What is your question? :)

Comment: I thought I had been clear enough in the post, but I apologize.  My question is, is there a "work around" that could be implemented in the PowerBI credentials encryption that would alleviate this issue?  I am working with a linux environment but trying to encrypt via a Microsoft environment.

Comment: To that, the answer is most likely "no" - if PowerBI depends on a Windows-specific (and proprietary) API (like CNG), then it'll only work on Windows.

Comment: I can't say I didn't anticipate that response.